# SESSION variable not saving values assigned from local or global variables

Tags: php, session-variables

Edit:When I assign a literal string value to a Session variable – no problem.  When I assign the value of a string variable to the Session variable, it works while on the page but there is strange text in it (always the same strange text) when I leave the page.

All of the pages start with `session_start();` on line 2 right after `<?php`, I've verified that they're starting the same Session ID, and all the pages are within the same domain.

Here is an example that *works*, i.e., the value is stored in the Session variable and is accessible from all pages:

```
$_SESSION['variablename'] = "Elmo!";
```

Here's an example that *does not work* across pages – the Session variable works while on the page but the value is not there when accessing it from other pages:

```
if(isset($_GET['variablename'])){

    $variablename = $_GET['variablename'];  
    echo $variablename;   // The value is "Elmo!"

    $_SESSION['variablename'] = $variablename;
    echo $_SESSION['variablename'];   // The value is "Elmo!"

}else{

// Do other stuff

}
```

***Edit 1:***

I access the Session variable in two ways:

1) A simple variable assignment:

```
$variable2 = $_SESSION['variablename'];
```

2) Inline in html:

```
<span>My favorite children's character is <?php echo $_SESSION['variablename']; ?></span>
```

I also check the Session variable values near the top of the page like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

I've tested it on a simple page without any includes.

The text in the session variable on the other pages is a partial line of text from a CSS file where I'm importing a font.

I hope you have some ideas.  All are welcome.  Thx.

Comment: We don't have enough infos. What do you mean by _strange text_? How do you read the session values in other pages? How do you include the pages in each other? Could you please provide a complete example?

Comment: you have `session_start();` on every page you need to access sessions from ?? < thats the answer to this about 99% of the time

Comment: I updated the question to add more detail as requested by @aendeerei.

Comment: @rtfm yes, as I stated in the question, not only is `session_start() ;` where it belongs on every page, I've verified that the Session IDs match.

Comment: Why are you using  **if(isset($_GET['variablename']))** for accessing the session from other pages.

Comment: @Hp_issei - the variable value is received in a URL parameter passed from another page.  I've verified that it's received correctly and can be used on the page.  I use a URL parameter because it's unpredictable where the variable value will be set.  It might be set on a search page, or it might even be entered by a user manually typing the domain name, e.g., typing in "domain.com/Elmo!" to the browsers address bar (I use .htaccess for url simplification).